# How to import a certain row from excel to python as an array?

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file with four rows of data. Now i want to import each of this rows to python as four single arrays, because I have to do some calculations with it.

I tried with pandas, but have some struggle to choose a special row in excel and to convert this into an array...

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'link')
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach? Can you provide some sample input and output? Once you have it in a single dataframe, you can just [index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) into each row to get a pandas series of that row

Comment: You are almost there :) Now to select only one array, you do `my_array = data["column name"]` and that's it!

Comment: No this doesn't work......When i write for example my_array = data[1] I get the error message KeyError: 1

Comment: @Gabriel98 do you get an error with `my_array = data.loc[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
data = []
with open (your_file_filepath, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        data.append(line)
```

Then you get an array of arrays of the lines in your file.

Instead of the for loop you can also write:

```
[data.append(line) for line in file]
```

Comment: What do you mean with your_file? The file-path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xlrd` (`pip install xlrd`):

```
import xlrd
with xlrd.open_workbook('file.xlsx') as wb:
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    rows = []
    for row in sheet.get_rows():
        rows.append([cell.value for cell in row])
```

Now `rows` will contain your 4 single *arrays* (lists in python) as: `row[0]` `row[1]` `row[2]` `row[3]`

Comment: I get the error message: NameError: name 'load_workbook' is not defined

Comment: Thank you. It works. But another question: I am not able to calculate with this arrays, because the entrys of row are "number: 55" and not only the number

Comment: That's because each row is a list of `xlrd.Cell` objects. I have edited the answer so you get a list of cell values for each row

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_excel(r'Book1.xlsx', header=None)

# Index desired row, here is the first, row `0`     
print(data.loc[0].values)

# or python list
print(data.loc[0].values.tolist())
```

using this dummy excel data

[image: dummy excel data]

gets the first row as an numpy array:

```
[u'a' u'b' u'c' u'd']
```

or a python list ("array"):

```
[u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd']
```